# Alternative to the GAE Conversion API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Now that the conversion API is discontinued is there a way to convert PDF files to an image in appengine / python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061732/now-that-the-conversion-api-is-discontinued-is-there-a-way-to-convert-pdf-files)

I'm needing an alternative to the Conversion API from the App Engine, the ones using this API what endup using after it was remove?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of conversions do you need to do?