# Now that the conversion API is discontinued is there a way to convert PDF files to an image in appengine / python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Now that the [Google Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview) has been discontinued is there a way to convert PDF files to images **in GAE**, specially python?

Looks like someone has [already requested](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8139) this from Google but there hasn't been any action.

A couple years ago [the consensus](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/UMVZdNevNhg) was it wasn't possible. Anything new out there that could help me out?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the issue report you linked to, there are two suggestions there:

1. Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python) to do it locally.
2. Use the [service](https://github.com/lookfirst/convert/) described in the comments that is "working well", "super easy to deploy", and "freely available", and good enough that "this issue can be closed".

The first is obviously not possible if you're running in a pure hosted environment that doesn't provide `ImageMagick`, but the second has no such problem. Of course neither is an "official Google" solution, but… so what?

If there's something specific you can't do either way, you'll have to tell us what.

Comment: The question: "is there a way to convert PDF files to images **in GAE**" is not answered by doing it locally or hosting a Node.js server. Neither of which I want to do.

Comment: Well, you already know the answer: Google doesn't host a service to do so anymore, so you have to go to a non-Google solution. Are you hoping that Google secretly has a different conversion API they haven't turned off, or looking for an excuse to avoid doing what you need to do, or looking for an actual solution?

Comment: The question is not "Y U NO HAVE PDF CONVERSION API GOOGLE? QQ" I was merely asking if anyone in the community had developed or stumbled upon anything new that would prevent me from having to host an external service to do pdf to image conversions. I'm sorry if this was unclear.